# Insert JSON data into HTML href tag (with placeholder variable)

Tags: javascript, html, json, href

I have some JSON data that holds three items: kicker, headline, and link. I insert the kicker and the headline with some JS into the designated HTML tags that hold a variable which is called `placeholder_1`. The number at the end increases by one (`placeholder_2`, `placeholder_3`, `placeholder_4`).

```js
var jsonData = [{
    "kicker": "Turkey",
    "headline": "Hatay hit by new 6.4-magnitude earthquake",
    "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/feb/20/turkey-new-6-point-4-magnitude-earthquake-hatay",
  },
  {
    "kicker": "Israel",
    "headline": "Benjamin Netanyahu accuses protesters of ‘trampling democracy’",
    "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/feb/20/israel-benjamin-netanyahu-accuses-protesters-of-trampling-democracy",
  },
  {
    "kicker": "Live",
    "headline": "Russia-Ukraine war: Joe Biden’s surprise visit to Kyiv ‘unprecedented in modern times’, says US",
    "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2023/feb/20/russia-ukraine-war-live-updates-latest-news-foreign-ministers-eu-ammunition-deal",
  },
  {
    "kicker": "Folly of Gossip",
    "headline": "A look into Sydney’s early drag scene",
    "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/gallery/2023/feb/20/folly-of-gossip-a-look-into-sydneys-early-drag-scene-in-pictures"
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  var k = 1;
  //loop through json data and insert into corresponding divs
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k)).innerText = jsonData[i].kicker;
    document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k = k + 1)).innerText = jsonData[i].headline;
    document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k = k + 1)).href = jsonData[i].link;
    k = k + 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <section>
    <div class="headlines">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h1 class="opinion-kk">Opinion</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="articles main-stories">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=1">
        <div>
          <p class="main-title">placeholder_1 / <a href="placeholder_3">placeholder_2</a></p>
          <p class="mainPara">Temporibus et repudiandae neque.</p>
        </div>
        class="sub-title"><strong>Et /</strong> <a href="#">Consectetur debitis non et amet eum</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="articles secondary-stories add-subtitle">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=2">
        <p class="secondary-title"><strong>placeholder_4 /</strong> <a href="placeholder_6">placeholder_5</a></p>
        <p class="sub-title"><strong>Ut /</strong> <a href="#">Quia tempora iste sed dolorem</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="articles secondary-stories">
        <img src="./assets/img/s_493.jpg">
        <p><strong>placeholder_7 /</strong> <a href="placeholder_9">placeholder_8</a></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</header>
```

But I fail to insert the link in the href tag in the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that these placeholders in your code are not ids, but simple text. I changed that (using 1 only id for the links, for both content and href attribute) and now it works perfectly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>News | Modx 3.0.3 </title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/custom.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js">
    </script>
    <link href="./assets/img/favi.png" rel="icon" sizes="any" type="image/png">
</head>

<body id="top">
    <header>
        <section>
            <div class="headlines">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <h1 class="opinion-kk">Opinion</h1>
                </div>
                
                <div class="articles main-stories">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=1">
                    <div>
                        <p class="main-title"><strong id="placeholder_1"></strong><a id="placeholder_2"></a></p>
                        <p class="mainPara">Temporibus et repudiandae neque.</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="sub-title"><strong>Et /</strong> <a href="#">Consectetur debitis non et amet eum</a></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="articles secondary-stories add-subtitle">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=2">
                    <p class="secondary-title"><strong id="placeholder_3"></strong><a id="placeholder_4"></a></p>
                    <p class="sub-title"><strong>Ut /</strong> <a href="#">Quia tempora iste sed dolorem</a></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="articles secondary-stories">
                    <img src="./assets/img/s_493.jpg">
                    <p><strong id="placeholder_5"></strong><a id="placeholder_6"></a></p>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>

    <script>
        var jsonData = [
            {
                "kicker": "Turkey",
                "headline": "Hatay hit by new 6.4-magnitude earthquake",
                "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/feb/20/turkey-new-6-point-4-magnitude-earthquake-hatay",
            },
            {
                "kicker": "Israel",
                "headline": "Benjamin Netanyahu accuses protesters of ‘trampling democracy’",
                "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/feb/20/israel-benjamin-netanyahu-accuses-protesters-of-trampling-democracy",
            },
            {
                "kicker": "Live",
                "headline": "Russia-Ukraine war: Joe Biden’s surprise visit to Kyiv ‘unprecedented in modern times’, says US",
                "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2023/feb/20/russia-ukraine-war-live-updates-latest-news-foreign-ministers-eu-ammunition-deal",
            },
            {
                "kicker": "Folly of Gossip",
                "headline": "A look into Sydney’s early drag scene",
                "link": "https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/gallery/2023/feb/20/folly-of-gossip-a-look-into-sydneys-early-drag-scene-in-pictures"
            }
        ]

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var k = 1;
            //loop through json data and insert into corresponding divs
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k)).innerText = jsonData[i].kicker;
                document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k = k + 1)).innerText = jsonData[i].headline;
                document.getElementById("placeholder_" + (k)).href = jsonData[i].link;
                k = k + 1;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```